# Rails app on Qovery not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hi I have deployed a Rails app with Postgres on Qovery, and went OK except for the hosts, in my environment file is set to 127.0.0.1, but Qovery gave an error, and external host which I put in the config.

That fixed that but then threw a different error about 127.0.0.1, which is the host in default db.yml file.

The error message for that is below.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

And the log is below, the main-friends forwarded host below is the one I put in to environment file to fix the original error message, and then got the one above. Seems to be nearly there and just have to fix this?

GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, br"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
HTTP_VERSION: "HTTP/1.1"
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: "143.159.177.24"
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST: "main-friends-wr7le49y8z1g6pul-gtw.qovery.io"
HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID: "95310e94cd72bb87b3be993fcd1192cc"
ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME: ""
REMOTE_ADDR: "10.244.16.1"
SERVER_NAME: "main-friends-wr7le49y8z1g6pul-gtw.qovery.io"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"

Any tips to fix welcome.

Thanks
```

Comment: did you fix your issue?

Comment: Hi yes changed to port 5431, which works also with Docker. Thanks